# Change tracing_subsciber's compact logger format

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

[tracing_subscriber](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber) provides a compact format that looks like this:

```
DEBUG nh::nixos:51: out_dir: TempDir { path: "/tmp/nh-os-uC6E1T" }
DEBUG nh::nixos:52: out_link "/tmp/nh-os-uC6E1T/result"
 INFO nh::commands:131: Building NixOS configuration
```

I want to change the symbols used ( `INFO`, `DEBUG`, etc), but I can't find how (if this is possible at all).

[/examples/examples/fmt-compact.rs](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tracing/blob/master/examples/examples/fmt-compact.rs)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. [`Format` hardcodes the level names](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/0.3.17/src/tracing_subscriber/fmt/format/mod.rs.html#1041-1053).

If you *really* want to do that, you can make your own type implementing [`FormatEvent`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/fmt/trait.FormatEvent.html) and overwrite `Format` with it via [`Layer::event_format()`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/fmt/struct.Layer.html#method.event_format).